# C++ Применение cin.getline к двумерным массивам char

Tags: c++, массивы, char, cin, getline

Вопрос таков - какие есть решения?

У меня есть объект, который я хочу целиком записать в файл, для этого у него должны быть все значения определённой длины, в нескольких полях мне нужно использовать двумерный массив char , запись идёт с помощью `cin.getline`, каждую строку нужно записывать отдельно (то есть не все вместе через пробел), а писать `arr[][]` в `cin.getline` нельзя, можно - `arr[]`, но тогда не понятно что выводит и работает некорректно.(По крайней мере так, как я писал)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ознакомился, не понял к чему это, можете конкретно указать на ошибку? Плюс я подкорректировал вопрос)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Понял, спасибо))

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin А вот насчёт текстовой информации опять не понял, вроде как здесь всё, что должно быть текстом является таковым

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 1. Комментарий удалил. 2. Это ведь результат работы программы, лучше мне его переписать? Мне кажется так нагляднее

Answer (score 0):

Оставляю свой ответ здесь, потому что сам ничего не нашёл, вдруг, кому-то это будет полезно, если так, прошу оценить))

```
int field_size = 256
int number_of_fields = 3
char arr[number_of_fields][field_size]={0};
    for (int i=0;i<number_of_fields;i++){
        cin.getline((char*)&arr+(i*field_size),field_size);
    }
// Test
    for (int i=0;i<number_of_fields;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<field_size;j++){
                    cout <<"["<< i << "]" << " [" << j << "] = ";
                    cout << arr[i][j] << endl;
            }

    }
```

Что здесь написано? Мы находим начало массива в памяти, затем заполняем первую строку массива, затем, чтобы ввести вторую строку в `char[1][0-256]` мы шагаем от начала массива на длину первого поля(256) и записываем строку во второе поле.
[image: Пример работы кода]

P.S Решение пришло в голову пока писал сюда этот вопрос, так что спасибо великому Stack Overflow!)))

Comment: Ну, например для динамических массивов такое решение не подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Многомерные массивы представляются как массивы массивов. Массив `T A[n][m]`  это `n` массивов из `m` элементов в каждом, и в `С++` в памяти они распологаются рядом_строка за строкой. Поэтому ничего необычного в том, что можно рассматривать его как одномерный массив, а `A[i]` как имя i _ того массива. `Массив А`, это просто `n * m` элементов типа `T` к которым мы обращаемся, как `n` массивов по  `m` элементов типа `T`.  Поэтому, в конкретном вашем примере, не нужны никакие преобразования(я бы не назвал это грамотным подходом), а нужно лишь обращаться к началу каждого массива. Начало i_той строки это есть адрес первого элемента этой строки, что можно получить любым из следующих способов:

```
&A[i][0]   //  адрес первого элемента i_той строки
A[i]       // указатель на i_тую строку
```

И написать просто:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_fields; i++) {
    cin.getline(arr[i], field_size);
}
```

Comment: Многомерный массив - это массив указателей. Иначе бы работало следующее array[row*cols+col]. А это не работает, а работает следующее *(*(array+row)+col), что эквивалентно array[row][col].

Comment: Я почему-то думал, что попробовал этот способ и он не сработал, хотя опробовав сейчас, всё работает, спасибо

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον, нет, многомерный массив, это не массив указателей, совершенно разные типы у многомерного массива и у одномерного массива указателей

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я говорю о внутреннем представлении, а не о типах. Компилятор Си транслирует array[i] в *(array+i). А первое - это т.н. "синтаксический сахар".